# UI Thread Splash Screen and long time running task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am working on a WPF application, app has a [SplashScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen.aspx) appears.

On the UI thread a method with a time consuming operation is running.

When clicking on the SplashScreen the application became unresponsive and END PROCESS windows modal dialogue appear.

This issue only happen when clicking on the splash screen otherwise no problems.

I would like to know

- What could be a possible solutions to this problem?
- If I use a Background Work, how could I connected it with my UI thread after the long running operation is completed?

Comment: With the background worker, in the `RunWorkerCompleted` method, close the splash screen EDIT: when i did this I had made a custom splash screen..

Comment: Just quick info....Where do you open the SplashScreen? In OnStartup?

Comment: You do the work on a background thread and use the Dispatcher to marshall UI updates back to the UI thread.  Standard threading work, much info about it on the internets and here.

Comment: @Will Where should I initiate the background worker... in OnStartup?

Comment: @GibboK: You know you have code that's running in the UI thread on startup, right?  Wherever that work is, move it to another thread.  If you can't figure out where that work is, debug, hit pause during startup, look at the UI thread to see where it is.